# Testing WCF services + Web interface - integrated approach

Tags: c#, wcf, automated-tests, soapui, coded-ui-tests

Not sure this is a very technical question but more of a looking for advice request.

Here's the thing: at the company I work in, I'm in charge of a project conformed by a couple of **WCF services** that interact with an already existing database, which at the same time is the resource database of a **web application**.

I have a series of smoke tests which include running requests that consume the WCF services AND also involve verification of processed data to this already existing Web application. I'm trying to automatize this smoke tests, meaning that I need to, for the web UI part, implement **Coded UI**. What I'm not so sure of is what to do with the web service part.

I though maybe of including **SoapUI** as being invoked by the Coded UI tests and shot two birds at once, but I have second thoughts whether coding the WCF operations passing the requests data into code would be a better solution, but I'm still not sure what approach would work best and would be more robust and easy to test at the same time.

Any ideas, opinions, or maybe some sharing experience?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: There is a WCF Test Client program, it provides a simple GUI interface that can drive WCF services. That will allow manual testing of the WCF services. A following stage might be to automate the use of the WCF Test Client via Coded UI. Another possibility is to use Visual Studio's Web Performance tests.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH, so basically you're saying WCF test client + Coded UI... that might work.